# SalesForce Commerce Cloud. Intercept data of users and orders

Tags: salesforce-commerce-cloud

I'm not so familiar with Commerce Cloud product but I need to know one point and I hope community can help me.
I need to implement a feature for customer who use SF Commerce Cloud and I would like to know it is possible or not. Customer wants to send some of data such as orders and users to an additional storage. This is requirement of local law and they have to implement it to do business.

Is it possible to intercept some actions like order placing, modifying, deleting and e-store customers creation, modifying, deleting? It would be great if you help me with direction where I can find additional information because after several attempts I can't get access to trial version of Commerce Cloud.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to do this in various ways. One way might be to implement a Javascript tracking integration that runs in the customer's browser and is referenced by the Storefront application that is running on SFCC. Another way would be to implement what is known as an Integration Cartridge which would implement several export jobs and/or service connections to your third party storage solution.

There is no trial version of the platform. In order to access an instance for development purposes, you will need to work through your customer's sandbox instances or become a Salesforce Partner.

Please review the Getting Started documentation. See also: [Demandware/SFCC prerequisites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50668105/demandware-sfcc-prerequisites/51127905#51127905)